# Loop within a loop?

Tags: powershell

Trying to scan the uninstall strings of the registry for certain software by searching using -match of the DisplayName value. I can get it to work with one piece of software but I am having troubles figuring out how to get it to work with a list of software. For example, I set Java, Silverlight, Shockwave, Adobe Reader and Adobe Font Pack as variables but cannot figure out how to loop them through the `foreach` command.

```
$PATHS = @("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
           "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")

# Java 8 Update 102 | 8.0.1020.14
$Javax86 = "Java 8"

# Microsoft Silverlight | 5.1.50901.0
$MSsilverlight = "Microsoft Silverlight"

# Adobe Shockwave Player 12.2 | 12.2.5.195
$AdobeShockwave = "Adobe Shockwave Player"

# Extended Asian Language font pack for Adobe Acrobat Reader DC | 15.007.20033
$AdobeReaderFont = "font pack for Adobe Acrobat Reader"

# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC MUI | 15.020.20042
$AdobeReader = "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC MUI"

$SOFTWARE = "" 
#@($Javax86,$MSsilverlight,$AdobeShockwave,$AdobeReaderFont,$AdobeReader)

foreach ($path in $PATHS) {
    $installed = Get-ChildItem -Path $path |
                 foreach { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath } |
                 Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match "$MSsilverlight" } |
                 Select-Object -Property DisplayName,DisplayVersion

    foreach ($app in $installed) {
        $DisplayName = "$($app.DisplayName)"
        $DisplayVersion = "$($app.DisplayVersion)"
    }

    if ($app.DisplayName) {
        $InstalledYes = "$DisplayName ($DisplayVersion) is installed"
    } elseif ($app.DisplayName -eq $NULL) {
        $InstalledNo = "$MSsilverlight is not Installed"
        #Write-Host "$SOFTWARE is not installed"
    }
}

Write-Host "$InstalledYes"
Write-Host "$InstalledNo"
```

Answer (score 3):

As you're using the `-match` operator, you could use the regex OR operator. Instead of building an array, use a pipe separated string:

```
$SOFTWARE = "$Javax86|$MSsilverlight|$AdobeShockwave|$AdobeReaderFont|$AdobeReader"

ForEach ($path in $PATHS) {

    $installed = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | 
                 ForEach { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath } | 
                 Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match $SOFTWARE } | 
                 Select-Object -Property DisplayName,DisplayVersion

    ForEach ($app in $installed) {
       $DisplayName = "$($app.DisplayName)"
       $DisplayVersion = "$($app.DisplayVersion)"

    }

    ....
```

Comment: You don't need tick marks after the pipes. Please don't use tick marks (ever) to continue a line.